# How to provide data to a master page? Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to know an appropriate way to provide information to a layout / master page.

A friend recommended adding this to `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    view()->composer('app', function($view) {
        $view->with('stages', Stage::all());
    });
```

This is working, but only on the homepage.

Here is how the data is used in the master page `app.blade.php`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  @if(isset($stages))
    @foreach($stages as $stage)
      <li><a href="department/{{ $stage->id }}">{{ $stage->name }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
  @endif
</ul>
```

Please assist, thank you.

Solution

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
use App\Stage;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function boot() {
  View::share('stages', Stage::all());
}

.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta use View::share() if you want to have the data throughout all the views. Inside the AppService Provider just do:

```
View::share('stages', Stage::all());
```

[Here you have the docs.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)

EDIT: to use the view facade, just add at the top of the file:

```
use View;
```

You can also use

```
view()->share()
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how to get access to the View facade?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still having an error. `Method [share] does not exist on view`

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated again.